# Javascript and HTML5, cooldown function bug

Tags: javascript, html

I've developed a game where you play as a cannon and just fire ammo, I plan on making it a simple physics simulation.  There is one problem, though.  I've tried to implement a cooldown function so the player can only fire one bullet every second, but sometimes (if the person holds the fire button down) it will fire 2,3, or 4 bullets at the same time, and then rest for 1 second.  Most of the time it only fires one bullet, but maybe 30% of the time it will fire a barrage of bullets at the same time.  I don't want this.

I want it to fire one bullet only, rest, then refire.  Here's my code:

For Keydown event handler:

```
else if( e.keyCode == 38  && CanFire) { //UP
            CanFire = false;            
            var bullet = new Bullet( Cannon.xpos, Cannon.ypos, 30, Cannon.angle );
            Bullets.push(bullet);               
            window.setInterval(Reload, 1000);

        }
```

Reload function:

```
function Reload() {
        CanFire = true;
        window.clearInterval(Reload);
    }
```

Global variable:

```
var CanFire = true;
```

Comment: The clearInterval accepts the intervalId, not the function name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clearInterval()` accepts the `intervalId`, not the function name.